# Declaration or statement expected in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a simple app trying to write a single byte to the UART Port via Bluetooth BLE in my Ionic/iOS app. I have the following function:

```
  onBtnPress(peripheral) {
    this.ble.write(
      // send 1 byte to switch a light on
      var data = new Uint8Array(1);
      data[0] = 2;
      this.ble.write(peripheral, 'FF10', 'FF11', data.buffer);
    )
  }
```

But when I compile it, I get the "Declaration or statement expected" error in Cordova.

The issue seems to be with the

```
var data = new Uint8Array(1);
```

I am NOT a programmer by trade and know even less about Angular. Is this not the correct way to declare an array?

Comment: `var data = [];` should do for an empty array...

Comment: You can also initialize it with a value like: `var data = [2];`, while `data[0] = 2;` is also perfectly okay. See some examples on dealing with arrays [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: You also might want to check what type of data `ble.write` expects. Maybe your solution is correct as it needs a [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) as input.

Comment: @Phonolog you are absolutely correct. I'm trying to send the character 2, which is 50 in Uint8Array apparently. And so the following code makes it work: var data = new Uint8Array(1); data [0] = 50;